# Remove all tab characters(\t) in excel cells

Tags: excel

Can I remove all tab characters(\t) in excel using 'Find And Replace'?

I can't use VBA or Excel Function, because sheet has many cells and don't know which cell has tab char.

I just want remove all tab characters(\t) in all cells in sheet.

EDIT)

Here my data.

`SARSPED    "   WKZLR42"    WKZ7F68`

WKZLR42 cell has tab characters front it.

Comment: Why can’t you copy and paste the tab you want to find in the find field?

Comment: @ 
CodeCamper
 It didn't work

Comment: Maybe you can provide a sample table of data we can paste in excel that demonstrates it is or is not working

Comment: I edit it, but when it convert space characters...

Comment: Are you sure it is not just space characters? When you upload to google sheets does it also convert to space characters?

Comment: Try the substitute() function.

Comment: when I paste google sheet, it paste next cell because it usual work.
how my client can input tab char in cell? usually tab char is 'move to next cell' in excel

Comment: @ 
Solar Mike
I can't use function because there has many cell and I don't know that which cell has tab char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This to me is also always such an annoying issue; the way it used to work was that one could use ALT Codes in the Find & Replace functionality to find these special characters. For a horizontal tab this would be <kbd>ALT</kbd> + 0009 on the keypad.

Note that there is a distinctive difference between ALT codes with *or* without leading zero's as per [this](https://altcodeunicode.com/) table. It appears that all the non-printable and non-displayable control characters (displayed in red in given link) can **not** be used within the office environment. I even think this is a Windows-wide issue as I tried to alter the hotkeys in the [Register-Editor](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/alt-codes-not-working/6e095387-5a5c-417a-9a99-566fac32583a) and the key-combination is not recognized.

Other tooling, like Notepad++, does seem to pick up the ALT code. So since you can't use VBA, you can't use formulae and you can't use the Find & Replace method; the two things that I could think of are:

---

**1) Notepad++**

Save your Excel as a CSV file and open in Notepad++. Within this application, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. Make sure to replace as per following screenshot:

[image]

Save your CSV and now load this back into your Excel.

---

**2) PowerQuery**

The 2nd option I can think of, depending on how your data is set up, is to load your data in PowerQuery. Within PQ select all your columns and right click on of the headers > 'Replace Values' > 'Advanced Options' > 'Replace using special characters' > 'Tab' > 'OK'.

[image]

Load back the data to Excel.